# Spam filter REST API Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

Does anyone know whether Marketing Cloud uses some spam filter for REST API calls?

I am currently implementing an API request on a website form which will upsert rows in a Data Extension in Marketing Cloud when someone ticks the optin box. I was wondering whether Marketing Cloud has set-up some threshold for max. api calls per time frame.

Thanks

Comment: You need to authenticate your rest calls with the tokens. Why should a valid token be ignored, i guess you won't give credentials to spam stuff ;) therefore every call without tokens will be ignored anyway. i would rather call this topic performance of rest api calls ;) But i do not know the answer... maybe you can just test it with concurrent api calls from a script like python? ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such functionality available out of the box. Writing your entire integration logic using front end code is not advisable, as it exposes all the credential details to your visitors. What I normally do is to build a custom endpoint to which the form is submitted. This can introduce e.g. async throttling, limit the number of subsequent request from same session and/or IP address, etc. Your API credentials will also not be exposed to the frontend.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Lukas! I will indeed do the request in the backend, to ensure the credentials are not exposed. In regards to the spam filter, I will set-up a max amount of requests per session. Hopefully this will work.